# How to get loop in nested Json Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this interface that contain Adress which is an object , how to get its value through *ngFor?

---

```
export  interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: Address;
}


export interface Address {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
  }

<div *ngFor="let oneuser of table">
  <p>{{oneuser.id}}</p>
  <p>{{oneuser.name}}</p>
  <p>{{oneuser.username}}</p>
  <p>{{oneuser.email}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: It needs to be in an array

Comment: Iterate through the interface? Something's new

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this

```
<div *ngFor="let oneuser of table">
<p>{{oneuser.id}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.name}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.username}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.email}}</p>
<hr>
<p>{{oneuser.address.street}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.address.suite}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.address.city}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.address.zipcode}}</p>

</div>
```

**Updated**

If `address` is `undefined` this will throw a common javascript error can't read street of undefined to solve this you can use safe navigation operator (`?.`)

```
<div *ngFor="let oneuser of table">
<p>{{oneuser.id}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.name}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.username}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.email}}</p>
<hr>
<p>{{oneuser.address?.street}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.address?.suite}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.address?.city}}</p>
<p>{{oneuser.address?.zipcode}}</p>

</div>
```