# How to access nested ngModel properties Angular 2?

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-ngmodel

I really hope someone could help me out.  I'm trying to reach a nested property in my model but I currently can not.

Here is my model in angular that I am trying to send to my Node and Mongo backend.

```
export class Address {
id: string;
name: string;
imgUrl: string;
address: {
  street?: string,
  suite?: string,
  city?: string,
  zipcode?: string
};
phone?:string;
}
```

Here is how I tried to access it with model.foo.boo but this obviously doesn't work i tried with [ ngModel ] and ( ngModelChange ) here is my html part:

```
 <form name="form" #f="ngForm" class="col-md-8 m-auto" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && upload()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !name.valid }">
    <label for="name">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" #name="ngModel" required>
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !name.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imgUrl">URL for profile image:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imgUrl" [(ngModel)]="model.imgUrl">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="street">Street:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" [ngModel]="model.address?.street" (ngModelChange)="model.address && model.address.street=$event"  >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="suite">Suite:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="suite" [(ngModel)]="model.address.suite">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" [(ngModel)]="model.address.city">
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does this questions help you out? it almost looks like a duplicate of what you are asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268676/how-to-get-loop-in-nested-json-object

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NgModelGroup` if you'd like to create a sub-group within a form:

```
<ng-container ngModelGroup="address">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="street">Street:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" [ngModel]="model.address?.street" (ngModelChange)="model.address && model.address.street=$event">
  </div>
  ...
</ng-container>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/wkVhyzjvUE821WykReEp)**

You can also create reusable AddressControl after reading the folowing article:

- **[Angular: Nested template driven form](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)**

Comment: This works only if I give the model properties values like you did  model: Address = {
    id: '1', name: 'Address',......}  If i do it like this it works without the NgModelGroup  but it just doesn't look right to me. I have already read the article you sent the properties show but they don't seem to be binded to the model when I log the model on the frontend and req.body on the backend. Thank you anyway